# ListView drag and drop animation

Tags: react-native

I am React Native developer, I want to create a ListView on which user can replace the list item to each other with drag animation. Is it possible with RN ListView? If Possible then let me know how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this module https://github.com/deanmcpherson/react-native-sortable-listview

It's basically a wrapper of `ListView` with drag and drop capability.